# What happens when refused entry at Canadian border?

Tags: usa, canada, buses, borders, denial-of-entry

Say I take the bus to go from the US to Canada, as a US citizen. If I am refused entry into Canada at the Canadian border, what happens next ?

The bus is going to leave without me, I have no way of going back home, no one to pick me up, what does one do ?

Comment: Wait for a bus going the other way?

Comment: Welcome to [Travel.SE]!  This question is essentially asking "how to I get from [remote point] to [somewhere else]", where [remote point] just happens to be a border crossing. As such, it is probably too broad to be effectively answered here.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert this questions asks what happens when refused entry to a country when you have no way of going back home

Comment: My point is that you're still inside the US at this point, and so your problem is really how to get between two points inside the US where one of them has limited transit options;  I doubt that there's anything particularly special about a border crossing.  And exactly what options are available at each border crossing is going to vary depending on the border crossing;  your options in Detroit/Windsor, Boisevain, MB, and Blaine, WA are going to be different.

Comment: Have you researched the documentation required for a US citizen to enter a land border into Canada? What makes you think you will be refused entry? The reason might make a more relevant question.

Comment: @WeatherVane The current COVID-19 situation is my concern

Comment: @MichaelSeifert Right, I see your point. This would be the St-Armand/Philipsburg crossing

Comment: In that case the bus and all its passengers will be turned around?

Comment: @WeatherVane not Canadians re-entering their home country

Comment: My guess is that the bus will probably not let you on board.

Comment: @Max For the moment Greyhound have not stopped their service

Comment: The leaders of the two countries have announced closure of the border.

Comment: @Frazic Why would you have no means to get home? Closing the border doesn’t necessarily mean there won’t be a bus going back the other way to your departure point.

Comment: @WeatherVane someone who has all the proper documents can still be refused entry, for example because of a conviction for driving under the influence of alcohol.  Frazic: as far as I'm aware the closing of Canada's borders does not apply to US citizens.

Comment: @phoog that's why I asked "What makes you think you will be refused entry?"

Comment: @phoog They announced today closing the border to all "non-essential" traval, there is just no official date announced

Comment: Why are you even thinking about this? Unless you have an exceptional reason to enter Canada you know you are going to get turned away. And even trying to cross the border adds to the risk of spreading the disease.

Answer (score 1):

The general answer to what happens to you when you are refused entry at a land border is that you are left at the border on the side you are coming from. In your case on the US side of the border. The bus will definitely leave without you (it will leave without you if you are taken off for secondary screening unless it is quite short.)

After that you are free to do what you want. You are in a normal part of the US, so you can call a taxi or an Uber to take you somewhere (such as a transport hub), or you can walk, or you can call someone to pick you up. Theoretically you might hitch a ride.

Comment: Is it normal or possible for people to wait for a similar bus on the same or similar route that might be coming at some point from Canada to go back home?

Comment: I was thinking more of a buying a new ticket situation of course.  It's technically a new/different journey.

Comment: Definitely not normal. The bus has no obligation to take you back. They probably don't pick up at the border.